# Partial Derivative of a function of x, y, and a function of x and y

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Let $F$ be a function of $x$, $y$, and $f(x,y)$.
Does $\dfrac{\partial{F}}{\partial{x}}$ take into account the change in $f$ due to the change in $x$?
For instance let $F(x,y,f(x,y)) = x+y+f(x,y)$. Then is $\dfrac{\partial{F}}{\partial{x}} = 1$ or $1+\dfrac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x}}$?

Comment: It's the latter formula. Derivatives (partial or not) are linear.

Comment: It would be the latter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is lousy notation, and completely ambigious as it is formulated.

To begin with, saying “F is a function of $x$, $y$ and $f(x,y)$” is bound to lead to confusion.
In order to even talk about partial derivatives unambiguously, you need to specify a coordinate system $(x,y,z)$, and define your function $F$ as a function of $x$, $y$ and $z$, where these are *independent variables*. Then “partial derivative with respect to $x$” means that you vary $x$ but keep the other variables $y$ and $z$ constant.

So, for example, if $F(x,y,z)=x+y+z$, then $\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}(x,y,z)=1$. And thus also $\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}(x,y,f(x,y))=1$, since we substitute $z=f(x,y)$ into the function $\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}(x,y,z)$, i.e., we let $z=f(x,y)$ *after* we have already differentiated.

On the other hand, if you let $z=f(x,y)$ *before* differentiating, then you are in fact considering another function, namely the composite function
$$
G(x,y) = F(x,y,f(x,y))
.
$$
The partials of $G$ are given by the chain rule, for example
$$
\frac{\partial G}{\partial x}(x,y)
=
\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}(x,y,f(x,y))
+
\frac{\partial F}{\partial z}(x,y,f(x,y))
\,
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)
.
$$
This expression is sometimes also written as
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}
\biggl(
F(x,y,f(x,y))
\biggr)
,
\tag{$*$}
$$
but note that this is different from
$
\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}(x,y,f(x,y))
$
that we had above. So you can't write just $\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}$ if it's ($*$) that you want to refer to.

Comment: I see what you did. Defining a new function G to distinguish between ∂G/∂x and ∂F/∂x. This seems logical. But could you explain then why the total derivative is denoted dF/dt? Wikipedia says that if F is a function of x,y,z, etc and t; and x,y,z, etc are dependent on t, then dF/dt = ∂F/∂t + (∂F/∂x)(dx/dt) + (∂F/∂y)(dy/dt) + (∂F/∂z)(dz/dt) + etc. Seems to me that we could have done what you did. Let G(t)=F(t,f1(t),f2(t),f3(t),...) where x=f1(t),y=f2(t),z=f3(t), and so on. Then differentiate w.r.t. t to get dG/dt like you did. Why call it dF/dt?

Comment: That's just to avoid introducing new symbols. Personally I think this often just causes confusion, and that it's clearer to give new names to the composite functions. But in physics, it's often the case that certain letters are strongly associated with certain physical quantities, and that the same letter is used for the quantity and for the functions which describe how it depends on other quantities. So they might want to write $T=T(x,y,z)=T(t)$ instead of $T=f(x,y,z)=f(a(t),b(t),c(t))=g(t)$. But once you do that, you may run into a lot of notational ambiguities.

Comment: So you agree that calling it dG/dt avoids causing any ambiguity and is a better notation than dF/dt?

Comment: In principle, yes, although what's better might be context-dependent, of course. Once you know what you are doing, $dF/dt$ usually works fine. But in order to sort out (or avoid) confusion, introducing a new letter is usually a very good idea. It might reduce readability, though. For example, the chain rule in the form $z=z(y)=z(y(x)) \implies dz/dx=(dz/dy) \, (dy/dx)$ may (or may not, depending on your taste) be easier to read than $(f \circ g)' = (f' \circ g) \cdot g'$.

Comment: The crux of the problem is that I am introduced to seemingly confusing notations before being introduced to the subject properly. I think for the time being I'll use different letters to define new functions until I get the hang of it. Once I become fluent I will be able to use the notations that are easy on the eye without confusing myself.

Comment: That sounds like a good plan!

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain this to me. It really helped me more than you could imagine.

Comment: Oh one last thing. Does ∂F(x,y,f(x,y))/∂x always mean that we evaluate ∂F(x,y,z)/∂x and plug in f(x,y) in place of z?

Comment: Well, if it's written like *that*, it's ambiguous, so you'd have to use your mind-reading powers to figure out what whoever wrote it actually *meant*.

Comment: Didn't you use the same notation when evaluating the partials of G?

Comment: Certainly not! I wrote $\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}(x,y,f(x,y))$, but you wrote $\frac{\partial F(x,y,f(x,y))}{\partial x}$. That makes a huge difference, because it makes it impossible to tell whether you mean what I meant, or if you mean ($*$).

Comment: Oh. Could you tell me the difference between them?

Comment: I already did (see the answer).

Comment: I see. And of these two which one is the same as just writing ∂F/∂x? The first one right?

Comment: $\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}$ on its own simply means $\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}(x,y,z)$, the function that you obtain by taking the partial derivative of the function $F(x,y,z)$ (holding $y$ and $z$ constant while varying $x$)...

Comment: And ∂F/∂x(x,y,f(x,y)) is the expression obtained after putting z=f(x,y) in it?

Comment: Yes, that's right!

Comment: Thanks! Another thing. You said that the meaning of ∂F(x,y,f(x,y))/∂x is ambiguous. In your answer it means ∂G/∂x(x,y). That is, it takes Into account the change in f(x,y) due to that of x, whereas ∂F/∂x(x,y,f(x,y)) does not (right?). For it to be ambiguous there has to be another possible interpretation of the former expression no? Could you tell me what that is?

Comment: No, no, no... **Nowhere** in my answer did I write it like that! In ($*$) I was careful to put **big brackets around the whole thing being differentiated**, precisely to *avoid* that ambiguity. And the two possible interpretations are of course the ones that are described in the answer, and in the comment “That makes a huge difference” above.

Comment: Ohhhh. ∂F(x,y,f(x,y))/∂x is ambiguous while ∂/∂x(F(x,y,f(x,y)) is not.

Answer (score 0):

For a function $F(x,y,f(x,y))=x+y+f(x,y)$, the derivative with respect to $x$ is
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(x+y+f(x,y))=\frac{\partial }{\partial x}x +\frac{\partial}{\partial x}y +\frac{\partial}{\partial x} f(x,y)$$
Assuming $y$ is not a function of $x$, this means
$$1+\frac{\partial}{\partial x} f(x,y)$$

Comment: I was confused by an answer given to me by someone in a previous post of mine. There I said that the partial derivative of x+y+z w.r.t. x is 1, but if z=2x it should have been 3. He answered by saying that 1 is the partial derivative while 3 is the total derivative.